# TextMate launch configuration

Tags: textmate

Is it possible to configure TextMate to launch the program I am currently writing (using the Command+R shortcut) with some command line parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language are you writing the program in? I'll use Python as an example.

Go to Bundles menu > Edit Bundles. Find and click on `Python` in the lefthand column. Click on `Menu Actions` in the middle column, then `Run Script` in the righthand column.

At the bottom of the window you will see the script that is run each time you use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Look for the line that begins with `TextMate::Executor.run`.

Right now, it appears for me as this:

```
TextMate::Executor.run(ENV["TM_PYTHON"] || "python", "-u", ENV["TM_FILEPATH"], :create_error_pipe => true, :use_hashbang => !ENV.has_key?('TM_PYTHON')) do |str, type|
```

Change it to this:

```
TextMate::Executor.run(ENV["TM_PYTHON"] || "python", "-u", ENV["TM_FILEPATH"], :create_error_pipe => true, :script_args => ["-arg1", "-arg2"], :use_hashbang => !ENV.has_key?('TM_PYTHON')) do |str, type|
```

Note the addition of `:script_args => ["-arg1", "-arg2"]`. Change the arguments in the parentheses to the arguments you want passed.

You can find other options to be used with `TextMate::Executor.run` in the [source file on GitHub](https://github.com/textmate/bundle-support.tmbundle/blob/master/Support/shared/lib/tm/executor.rb).